# How to interpret the dot product of vectors in different spaces of equal dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$ be two vectors in ℝ³, and let $A$ and $B$ be two distinct linear maps (matrices) that map ℝ³ to ℝ³. We perform the following operations:

Multiply $\mathbf{v}$ by $A$ to obtain a new vector $\mathbf{v'} = A\mathbf{v}$.
Multiply $\mathbf{w}$ by $B$ to obtain a new vector $\mathbf{w'} = B\mathbf{w}$.
Compute the dot product of $\mathbf{v'}$ and $\mathbf{w'}$, denoted as $\mathbf{v'} \cdot \mathbf{w'}$.

Is there a meaningful interpretation of that dot product?

Comment: No, the setup is much too general. But perhaps it may interest you that $(Av)\cdot(Bw) = (B^TAv)\cdot w = v\cdot(A^TBw)$.

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff How do you mean too general? Is the notion of similarity implicit with dot products removed after linear mapping?

Comment: I don't know what you mean with "similarity implicit with dot products". Maybe I should ask this: what are you hoping to get out of $(Av)\cdot(Bw)$? What prompted you to ask this question?

Comment: @NicholasTodoroff Sure, fair point. I am coming from a machine learning perspective where words are embedded as vectors with semantic meaning, e.g. the dot product between vectors for 'king' and 'queen' is large compared to a dot product between 'king' and 'bus'. And the similarity between words is encoded as locality in the vector space. Dot products are a notion of similarity in this context as the dot product is necessarily large for vectors with a small angle between them. If you project these vectors into different spaces, can the notion of a dot product 'similarity score' still hold?

Comment: That's a very different question! In that case I have an answer for you.

Comment: Even if you restrict to $B = I$, by varying $A$ you get exactly all bilinear forms.

Comment: @Riley what is the basis of your "meaning" space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question as clarified in the comments:

If $A$ and $B$ are projections then $(Av)\cdot(Bw)$ does not preserve $v\cdot w$ in any sense. (Unless we can say something about the relationship between $A$ and $B$; for instance if $A = B$ then $(Av)\cdot(Aw)$ will be a similar measure to $v\cdot w$ unless both $v$ and $w$ are nearly orthogonal to the image $\mathrm{im}(A)$ of $A$.)

Consider the case where $\mathrm{im}(A) \perp \mathrm{im}(B)$; then necessarily $(Av)\cdot(Bw) = 0$ regardless of what $v\cdot w$ is.